# OCR using a hidden Markov model

Tags: ocr, hidden, toolkit, markov, htk

I want to recognise English alphabets using a hidden Markov model. I have extracted features using the zoning method.

I want to use HTK toolkit for the training.  What is the format for giving the feature matrix as input to HTK?  How should I give input?

How can the feature vector matrix be placed into the train.scp file?

Comment: When you say "English alphabets", do you mean the 26 letters from A to Z?  Do you mean both upper and lower case?  Do you mean whole English words?  Something else?

Comment: Only the uppercase english letters. First I will develop a recognizer for each Uppercase english letter and then extend it to all the words. For now, I need how to train HTK.